# Jmeter TCP Sampler

Tags: jmeter, netty

We are running JMeter for connecting TCP Socket thorugh BinaryTCPClientImpl , We are getting the response code : 500

Response message: org.apache.jmeter.protocol.tcp.sampler.ReadException

JMeter Version : 2.9

Help out

Comment: Please Refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10683853/jmeter-tcp-sampler-incorrectly-reports-500

Question already asked.

Comment: I have already set the Parameter in jmeter property file still not working

Comment: Is server sending response properly?

Comment: Server sending the response

Comment: Server is sending the response but which format server has to send

Comment: that can be encoded.

Comment: Whats the next step to proceed

Comment: how can i send a few request per one channel connection using tcp sampler ?

Answer (score 1):

If this is the error

`ERROR - jmeter.protocol.tcp.sampler.TCPSampler:  org.apache.jmeter.protocol.tcp.sampler.ReadException: 
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.tcp.sampler.BinaryTCPClientImpl.read(BinaryTCPClientImpl.java:140)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.tcp.sampler.TCPSampler.sample(TCPSampler.java:414)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:429)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:257)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)`

then you have 2 options. The first (and much easier if it applies
to you) is to use the LengthPrefixedBinaryTCPClientImpl.  If this
applies to you, that is, if your responses are always the same fixed
sizes, you can simply set the tcp.binarylength.prefix.length property
and go about your business.
If that is not the case, then your other option is to extend
org.apache.jmeter.protocol.tcp.sampler.TCPClient.  It may help to get in
touch with the client team of this proprietary protocol, because after
all, they have implemented something that works.  You'll probably have
to extend it to look something like LengthPrefixedBinaryTCPClientImpl
read N bytes. Although, this runs the risks of reading too many or too
few bytes. If your application server ever miscalculates the size of
it's output, you suffer the consequences by getting another timeout or
leaving extra bytes in the buffer and reading them on the next iteration
(and then cascading errors).