# How to send some TCP hex packets in JMeter

Tags: sockets, tcp, jmeter

I'm working on a test scenario that it's testing a socket server over TCP with **JMeter**.
My test tree and `TCP Sampler` looks like this:
[image: TCP Sampler]

I used **BinaryTCPClientImpl** for **'TCPClient classname'**. It worked correctly and sent the hex packet (`24240011093583349040005000F6C80D0A`) to the server and I received the packet in server side too. After receiving the packet in the server side, it answered and **JMeter** received the response packet correctly too.

As you can see in the following test result, the `TCP Sampler` (Login Packet) send 4 times in the right way and responses are true (`404000120935833490400040000105490d0a`).
[image: Test Result]

The problem is that JMeter waits till the end of Timeout (in my case 2000ms) for each request and when it occurred then go to the next request. I don't want to wait for a timeout, I need a forward scenario, without the wait.

Comment: Did you try enabling `Close Connection` and/or `Re-use connection`?

Comment: @user7294900 Yes, I did. But it didn't make a change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution according to the following question and it helped me:
[Answer link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10683853/jmeter-tcp-sampler-incorrectly-reports-500?rq=1)

I just set the **End of line(EOL) byte value** to **10** that it means `return new line` in ASCI table.